# Uncommon "10 $digest iterations reached" case

Tags: angularjs

## Abstract

Hi, I think everyone has faced a problem entitled “`10 $digest iterations reached`”. Typically it is caused by recursively changing angular expression that never stop from changing or when watched expression generates new instance on each digest cycle.

My problem is that I don't have the above kind of problems in my code. The reason I face this problem is that I have pretty sophisticated level of nesting in my UI that takes more than 10 digest cycles to evaluate.

In order to prove that here is the html by removing which the problem disappears:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b-10" placeholder="Value not set" ng-disabled="workspace.mode === 'read'" ng-model="workspace.aircraftType.name">

        <p>ICAO</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b-10" placeholder="Value not set" ng-disabled="workspace.mode === 'read'" ng-model="workspace.aircraftType.ICAO">

        <p>IATA</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b-10" placeholder="Value not set" ng-disabled="workspace.mode === 'read'" ng-model="workspace.aircraftType.IATA">

        <p>Crew</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b-10" placeholder="Value not set" ng-disabled="workspace.mode === 'read'" ng-model="workspace.aircraftType.crew">

        <p>Weight</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b-10" placeholder="Value not set" ng-disabled="workspace.mode === 'read'" ng-model="workspace.aircraftType.weight">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Manufacturer</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-b-10" placeholder="Value not set" ng-disabled="workspace.mode === 'read'" ng-model="workspace.aircraftType.manufacturer">
    </div>
</div>
```

## Question

Changing architecture at this point is not an option I have way to many code written, so how do you increase 10 digest cycles limit to say 20 digest cycles?

Comment: Maybe try and break it into some ng-repeat logic based off the data structure instead of doing it individually?

Comment: I would probably read through this article http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html.  He discusses `$eval`, `$digest`, `$$phase`, etc. in depth, shows how to test the number of iterations, how to optimize, and how to modify the implementation if necessary.  ***WARNING*** this is a very technical deep dive into how angular works internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can change the number of digest cycles as follows:

```
app.config(function($rootScopeProvider){
  $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(20);
});
```

But, I am cautious to recommend this as a general approach since, in all likelihood, the problem lies elsewhere your code (which is not specified in the question) and it just manifests itself in this section. The number of digest cycles should not be a function of nesting, so the fact that you reached 10 is a problem in and of itself.

Comment: Thank you very much @New Dev, I will take it seriously and try to identify the issue and optimize the overall architecture but not right now, thanks

Comment: Appreciated +1. Just curious does it come up with angular `1.3`/`1.4` or it was already there?

Comment: @pankajparkar, quick glance at [src code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.0/src/ng/rootScope.js) shows that it has been there from at least v1.1.0

Comment: @NewDev Thanks lad..for you reference..today I learned new thing..Thank you sir..